# Unnecessary spaces generated during Subsurf

Tags: modeling, modifiers

so my problem is that I've created a model that has a parametric form, so when I use subsurf to smoothen out the edges, these sort of faces are generated that interfere with even my freestyle outlining. How do I solve this problem?[image][image]

Comment: Are there any topological oddities going on there? Internal faces or otherwise non-manifold stuff? (You can select non-manifold geometry with `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+M`). If not, is it possible you could [upload your .blend](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/344/599)?

Comment: I used the default cube, merged it to a vertice, and then traced out a form, created a face and extruded a form. Then I used subsurf to smoothen the faces. Attached is the blend file. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4623" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4623/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to having n-gons or a mesh problem can we see a photo of your mesh or can we take a look at your blend file?

EDIT: It might be better to just smooth the model then add edge split. First u will need to remove doubles, select your mesh then press w and select remove doubles[image]
Then exit edit mode and select smooth 
[image]

Then add edge split 
[image]

Comment: I used the default cube, merged it to a vertice, and then traced out a form, created a face and extruded a form. Then I used subsurf to smoothen the faces. Attached is the blend file. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4623" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4623/)

Comment: check edit please

Comment: No problem mate, please accept my answer if u don’t need any more help